# I have Windows 7 on a 1TB HDD and I have installed UBUNTU on 240GB OCZ SSD

Tags: dual-boot, windows, boot-repair

[Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5606081/)

I run boot-repair as I cannot boot up Ubuntu. It suggested using Gparted?  I want to be able to boot up my computer and choose either Windows or Linux everytime. I used EasyBCD to add Linux but then when I run it at bootup is comes up with:

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem,     bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.
=================== Advice displayed in case of recommended repair
```

Comment: Why not try just reinstalling with the default setting 'Install alongside Windows' in the installer?

Comment: I wanted to manually arrange the partitions on the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your Windows discs (1TB and 96GB), then format your SSD and reinstall Ubuntu on it. Reboot and check it works, then re-connect your Win discs.